# Copiar valores de um array PHP

Tags: php, array

Tenho dois `arrays` dinâmicos no meu sistema:

```
Array 1:

$nome { [0] => nome1
        [1] => nome2
}

Array 2:

$contagem { [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 4
            [4] => 5
}
```

Esses dois `arrays`, são dinâmicos, podem ter vários números de entrada, a `variavel` nome pode ter vários nomes, e a contagem, vários valores (até cem), mas sempre seguindo esse padrão, por razões de se encaixar nos padrões da empresa, minha dúvida é, supondo que a variável $nome, tenha 2 valores, como eu faço para duplicar á variável $contagem, e que na variável duplicada posso ir cada nome, ex:

```
Array 1:

$nome { [0] => nome1
        [1] => nome2
}

Array 2:

$contagem { [0] => nome1
            [1] => nome1
            [2] => nome1
            [3] => nome1
            [4] => nome1

            [5] => nome2
            [6] => nome2
            [7] => nome2
            [8] => nome2
            [9] => nome2
}
```

PS: no caso duplicar a variável `$contagem`, foi somente por ter 2 nomes na variável `$nome`, se fosse 3 nomes, seria triplicar;

Comment: A contagem será sempre 5 posições para cada nome?

Comment: Obrigado por responder @MarcelodeAndrade, não esse array é dinâmico, depende de um cálculo feito numa página anterior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilize a função [array_fill](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php) para criar um `array` com tamanho e valor pré-definidos. Ex:

```
<?php

$nomes = ["José", "Maria"];
$contagem = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

$a = [];

foreach($nomes as $nome) {
    $arrTemp = array_fill(0, count($contagem), $nome);
    $a = array_merge($a, $arrTemp);
}

var_dump($a);
```

[**Demonstração**](https://ideone.com/Kbio2h)

Comment: Perfeito @Valdeir Psr, funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado pela ajudar! Cheers